# Taurus: Pull numerical value (no quotes) from CSV into JSON

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

How can I pull data from a CSV into JSON without adding a quote?

This is what I want generated:

```
{"id" : 12345}
```

I have a rest service that only allows a numeric value, but I'm unable to pull from the CSV without adding quotes.

```
body: { "id": "${id}"}
```

Works, but it adds quote to the message {"id" : "12345"}

```
body: { "id" : {id} }
```

returns:

```
 Error when reading config file 'test.yml': while parsing a flow mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 34, column 13:
          body: { "id": ${id} }
                ^
expected ',' or '}', but got '{'
  in "<unicode string>", line 34, column 22:
          body: { "id": ${id} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#HTTP-Requests) you need to put the body string into quotation marks:

```
body: '{ "id": ${id}}'
```

Full example just in case you want to validate the approach:

```
execution:
  - concurrency: 1
    scenario: quick-test
scenarios:
  quick-test:
    requests:
      - url: 'http://example.com'
        jsr223:
          - language: groovy
            execute: before
            script-text: 'vars.put("id", "12345")'
        method: POST
        body: '{ "id": ${id}}'
```

More information:

- [Taurus YAML Tutorial](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't notice that after reading the documentation 1000 times.